# Download file request chrome extension with headers

Tags: google-chrome-extension, download

I'm developing google chrome extension, I want to send headers in the request like:

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: 'http://test/api/file/download',
    filename: "file_from_web_api.exe",
    headers: {
        ProfileID: "1"
    }
});
```

But I'm getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of downloads.download(downloads.DownloadOptions options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Error at property 'headers': Invalid type: expected array, found object.

My question is how to append headres to download request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) headers need to be a Array of objects

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: 'http://test/api/file/download',
    filename: "file_from_web_api.exe",
    headers: [
        {'ProfileID': '1'}
    ]
});
```

you can also try to create a header object first and then add it to the array [look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/Headers)

EDIT: try with header object

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: 'http://test/api/file/download',
    filename: "file_from_web_api.exe",
    headers: new Headers({
        'ProfileID': '1'
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm getting other error: `Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of downloads.download(downloads.DownloadOptions options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Error at property 'headers': Error at index 0: Unexpected property: 'ProfileID'.`

Comment: oh my bad i think it should be  {'ProfileID': '1'}

Comment: The extensions documentation is bad of course but it still explicitly states the object should have keys `name` and `value` e.g. `{name: 'ProfileID', value: '1'}`

Comment: oh cool, Codey let us know if it work so we can update the answer. (the docs dont have examples)